# What is the "MCD" configuration created as a result of the `dotnet publish` command?

Tags: .net-core, build, configuration, dotnet-publish

When I apply the `dotnet publish` command I see three folders created in the `bin` folder: `Debug`, `Release`, and `MCD`.

What exactly is the `MCD` configuration, and what is this configuration for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely a result of the environment variable `Platform=MCD` existing, as it often will on a machine configured by HP.

See [this article](http://bsoni24.com/why-there-is-a-mcd-folder-in-my-bin-directory/) and [this github discussion](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/3910#issuecomment-75112236) for more detail:

> The issue you are seeing might be related to the way HP machines are setup -- they have an environment variable called Platform, set to MCD which is why you are seeing this...

If it is causing a problem, there is nothing wrong with removing this variable as far as I know.  This [blog post](https://chapmanworld.com/2016/11/14/invalid-platform-variable-hpv-or-mcd/) from *Chapman World* agrees.  And if it did break something it's easy to put the variable back. So the risk is small.

Alternatively, you could safely ignore or discard the unwanted build output now that you know its origin.

Comment: I think using generic environment variables like `Platform` (without any namespacing) in msbuild is a terrible design decision. Please provide feedback on https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/issues/2713 if you would like it to be "fixed".